# How to have a single textfield for exp-month and exp-year

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe for CC processing and used the stripe example form and JS code. The form has two separate fields for expiration month and year. each has `data-stripe="exp-month"` and `data-stripe="exp-year"`

I'd like to use one textfield for month and year and have the user enter the input like: `10/2020`

**Question**

Since stripe reads the data based on `data-stripe` attribute. Is there a way I can parse the input `10/2020` from one textfield and programmatically set the `data-stripe` attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how everything is glued together and being sent, but you could have hidden input fields with the `data-stripe="exp-month/year"` attributes and then split the visible input value on / and set the hidden values.

Here is a rather basic [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lahinepiqe/edit?html,js,console,output) where you can see month and year in the console output.